# Send Email notification if task is not completed 7 days prior to the due date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I am working with SharePoint 2013 Designer Workflow. I am not sure how to Send Email notification if task is not completed before 7 days of a Due Date.

Answer (score 2):

Typically you'd create a new workflow on the task list the triggers on item creation. It is set to pause until the due date minus 7 days. Then you do a check to see if the status is not complete. If that's the case, you send an email.

Comment: I am using the same Task list for different workflows but the Notification should be sent to only one workflow and also in that workflow in one stage. But if i run the workflow in Task list for Due Date it will send emails to all the workflows. And also all stages in that particular workflow. Is there any other option?

Comment: Then you'd put some conditional logic to check for a content type or field or status that if it meets the condition, then pause. If not then the workflow just exits without doing anything.

Comment: In my case if Task assigned To is a group then workflow should run and if it is assigning to User then it should not run. How to write condition for this?

Comment: Are the groups SharePoint groups? You might be able to determine it by doing a substring/regex on the assigned to field.

Comment: yes they are sharepoint groups

Comment: If you name all these groups consistently, like XXX Group, YYY Group, you could use an Extract Substring From End of String action to grab the last 5 characters. Then evaluate if that equals Group if so end the workflow otherwise do the reminder logic.

Comment: Extract sub string method is working. Thanks Eric..

Comment: If i am writing the workflow to task List then how can i get the links to current Item to show in the email. And also how to get the links to original list Item?