# Email alert some day before dead line

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I´m a new in Sharepoint and I have to do this, I need to send an email 7, 5, 3 day before a due date.

I´m using SPD 2013

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm seeing a difference from [that question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97554/send-email-notification-if-task-is-not-completed-7-days-prior-to-the-due-date) in that the requirement here is to send notifications on multiple days (unless the same steps apply)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below mentioned steps to send an email using SPD

[image]

You can mention the day before you want to send an email whatever you want.

Comment: Is that works for you?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, here is link to the answers/options that the community presented me with.

[Is it a hindrance to have a workflow wait for a long period of time?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164270/is-it-a-hindrance-to-have-a-workflow-wait-for-a-long-period-of-time)

Comment: Summary: Use Information Management Policy to kick off a  SPD workflow that does NOT wait and only emails. Give it 3 stage for 7,5,&3.